# How can I share images from an Array that uses ImageView feature?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-imageview

I have a doubt.

How can I share images from an Array that uses ImageView feature?

My array has more than 100 images, an example:

```
Final int [] photos = {
                R.drawable.abrir_a_boca,
                R.drawable.rooms,
                R.drawable.firmly,
                R.drawable.agradeca,
                R.drawable.alfaiate,
                R.drawable.ancora,
}
```

To share I'm trying to use Intent.ACTION_SEND

```
Set.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            Public void onClick (View v)
            {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse (photos???);

                SharingIntent.setType ("image / *");
                SharingIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                StartActivity (Intent.createChooser (sharingIntent, "Share image using"));

            }
        });
```

How can I share the images?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: `an Array that uses ImageView feature?` ?? Where do you have such an array? I only see an array with integers. The integers are resource id's.

Comment: `My array has more than 100 images`. No your array does not contain images. It contains integer values. Resource id's.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do some operations before you share your image, so add the permission in your `Manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Fist, create a `Bitmap` object from your drawable resource:

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.xxxx);
```

Then, get the path for you share your image

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/yourImage.jpg";
OutputStream out = null;
File file=new File(path);
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
path=file.getPath();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+path);
```

And finally, create your intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share with..."));
```

Comment: Apart from that you handle one image only and that it does not work on Android 7, your code uses an intermediate bitmap which is not needed. Moreover you would gladly change a png to jpg. Better would be if you just copied the file without using a bitmap. After having determined the file name. As now you just create a different name.

Comment: Obrigado, Luiz Fernando.
Daqui a pouco irei fazer um teste e posto aqui.
Abraço!

Comment: Abraços!, qualquer coisa estou disponivel!

Comment: Olá, Luiz.
Esqueci de mencionar, na verdade estava querendo compartilhar uma imagem que estava sendo exibida na tela, é porque a pessoa clica na imagem e as imagens são randômicas e são mais de 100.

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d5a3/l0b5eobtpdbeoenzg.jpg

Segue um exemplo da tela.